# Windows-service should send message to the user notification area

Tags: notifications, windows-services

A Delphi-Service-App should check the existence of Updates for a specific App and inform then User, if this happens. Only the last part is the problem, especially because the Service isn't allowed to do this directly. Instead of this, the Service should start a specific NotifyApp with some params in the context of the current user. Unfortunately, this fails.

I tried to calc the Token of the current user via WtsGetActiveConsoleSessionID and WTSQueryUserToken, and then tried to start CreateProcessAsUser with that Token. This fails saying, here are not enough rights, in german "Der angeforderte Vorgang erfordert erhöhte Rechte". I cannot understand that, because I'm logged in as an admin, not a sys-admin, and on the other hand the Notify-App doesn't need any spezific rights.

Question: How can this happen, what is wrong and how can that problem be solved?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.